# Laravel Livewire is including <head> tag twice

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I've been following the Livewire docs and screencasts to build my new app, but I could be doing something wrong because the `<head>` tag is been included twice.

Here is my code:

**routes\web.php**

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Livewire\User\All as UserAll;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified'
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');

    // Users
    Route::prefix('users')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', UserAll::class)->name('users-all');
    });
});
```

**App\Http\Livewire\User\All.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\User;

use Livewire\WithPagination;
use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class All extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $search = '';

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user.all', [
            'users' => User::search('name', $this->search)->paginate(10)
        ]);
    }
}
```

**App\View\Components\UserLayout.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class UserLayout extends Component
{

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('layouts.user');
    }
}
```

**resourse\views\layoutsuser.blade.php**

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])

        <!-- Styles -->
        @livewireStyles
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased dashboard">
        <x-jet-banner />

        <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
            @livewire('navigation-menu')

            <!-- Page Heading -->
            @if (isset($header))
                <header class="bg-white shadow">
                    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                        {{ $header }}
                    </div>
                </header>
            @endif

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <main>
                {{ $slot }}
            </main>
        </div>

        @stack('modals')

        @livewireScripts
    </body>
</html>
```

**resourse\views\livewire\user\all.blade.php**

```php
<x-user-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Users') }}
        </h2>
        <input wire:model="search" type="text">
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                    <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>{{ __('ID') }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ __('Name') }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ __('Email') }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ __('Date') }}</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach ($users as $user)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->created_at->format('M, d Y') }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <div class="my-7">
                            {{ $users->links() }}
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-user-layout>
```

If I remove the `<x-user-layout>` tag in the blade, the problem seems to be fixed, but then livewire doesn't work.

I've tried many solutions, but nothig works. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: does all.blade.php extends of layoutsuser.blade.php? Did you create 2 components to render them both? or all.blade.php has nothing to do with layoutsuser.blade.php

Comment: @haruk1515 Yes, I created the component (`App\View\Components\UserLayout.php`) to load the `resources\views\layouts\user.blade.php` template layout, and its extend from all.blade.php with the `<x-user-layout>` tag

Comment: I'am not an expert on livewire, however you don't need to render the layout 'layoutsuser.blade.php',just render the content(all.blade.php), in livewire on the function render(), you need to make a change:

public function render(){
   return view('livewire.user.all', [users' => User::search('name', $this->search)->paginate(10)])->extends("layouts.user")->section("content");
   } ,
as you can see with extends you include the layoute 'user' and with 'section', you specify the name of the section, for later on make use of @yield("content") 
and @section("content")@endsection

Comment: In my case I prefer to use @includes with @sections/@yield to extend layouts, I don't use x-layouts, basically if you interested in using the other way, just make the change on livewire,
then go to  layoutsuser.blade.php,where it says <main>{{ $slot }}</main> use instead @yield('content'), go to all.blade.php and replace the <x-user-layout></x-user-layout> with a 
div(because livewire needs to be wrapped on a single div, to be able to work), and finally add the content with @section("content") ...(all content).. endsection

Comment: if this didn't help, i can add an answer with your code

Comment: @haruk1515 thanks a lot, but your solution did not work for me... May be I'm fall into a big problem with a very easy solution, I don't know. I'm very new to Laravel and Livewire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in

App\Http\Livewire\User\All.php add layout

```
 public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user.all', [
            'users' => User::search('name', $this->search)->paginate(10)
        ])->layout('layouts.user');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I will add an answer just to clearify things

**App\Http\Livewire\User\All.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\User;

use Livewire\WithPagination;
use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class All extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $search = '';


/**
 * We add extends() and section()
 * In ->section(), I added layouts.user assuming that is the layout that all.blade.php will extend of (if it's not, change it)
*/

function render() {
    return view('livewire.user.all', ['users' => User::search('name',$this->search)->paginate(10)])->extends("layouts.user")->section('content');
}
}
```

**resourse\views\livewire\user\all.blade.php**

I changed `<x-user-layout>` and `<x-slot>` with a `<div>` and as i said in my early comments, you need to wrapp all the content in a `<div>` to make it work. If you want to use headers apart, instead of using `<x-slot>` use `@include("")` (personal recomendation).

I will add a link if you want to learn more about the blade directives:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#blade-directives

```
<div> 
    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                    <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>{{ __('ID') }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ __('Name') }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ __('Email') }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ __('Date') }}</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach ($users as $user)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->created_at->format('M, d Y') }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <div class="my-7">
                            {{ $users->links() }}
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**resourse\views\layoutsuser.blade.php**

In your livewire component All.php, there is specified now the section that has to be used `->section("content")`,the only thing remaining is to use `@yield` instead of `{{ $slot }}`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])

        <!-- Styles -->
        @livewireStyles
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased dashboard">
        <x-jet-banner />

        <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
            {{-- @livewire('navigation-menu') --}}

            <main>
                @yield('content') 
            </main>
        </div>

        {{-- @stack('modals') --}}


        @livewireScripts
    </body>
</html>
```

**routes\web.php**

I noticed, that you don't call the class All, that is the responsible of rendering the view, you calling UserAll:: class, however I don't really know the functionality of this class, so instead try adding this route, to test

```
Route::get('/all', All::class)->name('users_all_test');
```

Try it, and let me know how it went.

You can use the livewire documentation too:
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components

there you can find explanations of ->extends(), and ->section()

Comment: But I also learned a couple of things from @haruk1515 

Comment: @RogerTM Glad to hear that, keep the good work